# Не сохраняются изменения git

Tags: git, git-push

Все привет!

Ситуация такая: есть bare репозиторий на сервере. Соединяюсь сервером по ssh. при попытке "сохранить" изменения на локальном репозитории (т.е. push, commit) операции идут нормально. При просмотре на сервере git log - коммиты видит. Но изменения при этом не сохраняются.

**Решение**:

Виной всему оказалось моя собственная невнимательность и тупость.

Дело в том, что в пушил не в ту ветку. Правда это я понял только после того, как пересоздал репозиторий.

Comment: а как Вы определили, что изменения "не сохранились"?

Кстати, если с локального репозитория делать вначале push, а потом commit, то да, на удаленном сервере изменения не будут сохранены.

Comment: 1. насчет последовательности push commit - я знаю, что сперва делается коммит(слепок) затем пуш (как я понимаю копирование в репозиторий)
2. Элементарно посмотреть файлы. сервер - виртуальный дебиан, к которому я могу обратиться с помощью putty. 
3. может я неправильно сформулировал проблему - изменения не сохраняются на сервере. Все коммиты - записывает, а сами файлы - нет

Comment: если `git diff --stat <sha>` для коммита показывает список файлов, значит они там есть.

Хорошо будет, если в вопросе распишете полную последовательность комманд, которую Вы вводите. Так будет легче понять, где произошло ЧП.

Comment: Это очень странно, учитывая как работает git. Он не создаст новый хэш, пока не проверит наличия и получения всех измений с локального репозитория. попробуйте скачать все файлы с удаленного сервера и сравните с локальной версией.

Comment: А Вы на сервер делаете `git pull` или `git fetch`?

Comment: Плюс за самокритичность )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@garmayev](/users/30646/garmayev)](/users/30646/garmayev)

> Ситуация такая: есть **bare** репозиторий на сервере.
>
> ...
>
> Элементарно посмотреть файлы. Сервер - виртуальный дебиан, к которому я могу обратиться с помощью putty.
>
> Может, я неправильно сформулировал проблему - изменения не сохраняются на сервере. Все коммиты - записывает, а сами файлы - нет

**bare-репозитории** не содержат файлов (точнее, рабочего каталога с файлами) по определению, только наборы изменений. Что характерно, буквально позавчера про это читал.

Цитата [отсюда](http://githowto.com/ru/bare_repositories):

> В удаленных репозиториях нет смысла хранить рабочие файлы на диске (как это делается в рабочих копиях), а все что им действительно нужно — это дельты изменений и другие бинарные данные репозитория. Вот это и есть «чистый репозиторий».